# Why is SAT not in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, p-vs-np

I'm studing P and NP complexity classes. I like know, why is SAT not in P? Is it because I can not determine if any Boolean expression is satisfiable?

Comment: We don't know whether SAT$\notin$P or not, and we certainly don't have any idea why that would be true (other than geometric complexity theory).

Comment: Have you tried reading the Wikipedia articles about SAT and P vs. NP?

Comment: Please read [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/in-basic-terms-what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard/) on this topic; I'm closing as duplicate since the answer to your (quite uninformed, to be honest) question is there.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to determine whether a boolean expression is satisfiable, the question is how quickly it can be done.

If there are $n$ variables, then we can try all $2^{n}$ possible truth assignments, and eventually we'll find if there is a satisfying one, but this is not *polynomial* time with respect to the size of the input.

There *might* be some polynomial time algorithm that does solve SAT, we don't know, however SAT is NP-complete, which gives strong evidence that there isn't a polynomial time algorithm. It all comes down to whether P=NP or not.

Comment: I'm confusing, The SAT problem is finding a formula such that is satisfiable for all entries?
Or is finding a set of assignments to the formula such that it is satisfiable?
Or is finding several formulas that are satisfiable for all entries?

Comment: In the SAT problem, you are given a boolean formula, and you want to know if there's at least one way to satisfy it. So your second definition.